# Android: How can get paint on mapviews?

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, paint

I am getting the `MapView` of current location by passing longitude and latitude parameters correctly. But i want to draw paint just like free hand (i.e names or lines and so..on) on that `MapView` image. from that i want total image of  `MapView`image on that paint by user.
How can I do this?

when user send his path to another user like shown below...

[image]

Comment: @Hesham Saeed i want not only paths just names and etc.. i want to use paint options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an overlay.  [See this example Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview/#Part2)

Here's example code:

```
public class overlayGeoPoints  extends Overlay {

    private GeoPoint geoPoint;
    private int radius = 20;

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView mapView){
          this.geoPoint = geoPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

        // put your logic here to draw on the overlay
        // ie draw a circle
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);

        int px = point.x;
        int py = point.y;
        Paint paint = new Paint(paintSecondary.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        hl.setColor(intColor);
        canvas.drawCircle(px, py, radius, paint);
        canvas.save();

    }
}
```

Just add this overlay to your map.

**Edit**

Here is a step by step (generic):

AFTER your map object (map) is created

```
// get a handle to the map overlays
List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();

// reset overlays as necessary
//overlays.clear();

// create your custom overly class
overlayGeoPoints olay = new overlayGeoPoints();

// append overlay to map overlays
overlays.add(olay);

// tell the map object to redraw
mapView.postInvalidate();
```

Comment: from that i already get the total map view using itemized overlay... from that just i want to paint on that view

Comment: You cannot directly draw on the mapview.  You can only overlay the map - on which you can draw anything you want - pics, dots, text, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you question, you want to capture the drwaing movements and display then over the map.

**Steps:**

- Create a new class extending Overlay
- Override `onTouchEvent()` to get the positions (x,y) the user taps and move finger on, convert them to Geopoint and add the geopoints to a Path object. Call `invalidate()` to have the map redrwan.
- Override `onDraw()` to draw the path build above with `canvas.drawPath()`
- Finally, add the overlay to the end of mapView.getOverlays(), to ensure this overlay is the first getting touch events.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This file is MapViewDemoActivity.java
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;

   import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

       public class MapViewDemoActivity extends MapActivity {
        private MapView mapView;

       @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

         mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
         mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //display zoom controls
     }

      @Override
         protected boolean isLocationDisplayed() {
          return false;
     }
```

this like is greate to usefull to all http://n3vrax.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/drawing-overlays-on-android-map-view/